# How to set hbase-site.xml in sbt classpath

Tags: sbt, hbase, classpath

I am trying to connect HBase from my sbt scala project. I need to set `hbase-site.xml` in the classpath. How can I do this? HBase is located in virtual machine and sbt scala project is located on my windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try add the following dependency settings in your `build.sbt`, assuming your hbase-site.xml resides under `/path/to/hbase/conf/`:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= {
    val baseDir = baseDirectory.value
    val customDirs = ("/path/to/hbase/conf") +++ ("/path/to/hadoop/conf")
    val customJars = (baseDir ** "*.jar") +++ (customDirs ** "*.jar")
    customJars.classpath
}
```

More `sbt` library management info can be found [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html).

[UPDATE]

In addition to the reported error, custom libs in this case shouldn't be limited to `*.jar`.  See revised settings below:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= {
    val baseDir = baseDirectory.value
    val customLibs = (baseDir ** "*.jar") +++ file("/path/to/hbase/conf") +++ file("/path/to/hadoop/conf")
    customLibs.classpath
}
```

Here's an alternative way using `map`:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile <++= baseDirectory map { base =>
    val baseJars = (base ** "*.jar")
    val customLibs = baseJars +++ file("/path/to/hbase/conf") +++ file("/path/to/hadoop/conf")
    customLibs.classpath
}
```

Comment: Hi @Leo, Thanks for reply. I have done above chnages in my `build.sbt` file but got this error `D:\scala-hbase\build.sbt:18: error: value +++ is not a member of String
    val customDirs = ("/etc/hbase/conf") +++ ("/etc/hbase/conf")
                                         ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?`

Comment: My bad. `("/path/to/hbase/conf") +++ ("/path/to/hadoop/conf")` is obviously wrong.  Please see updated answer.